# Revoked certificate - app store metrics stop - are those gone for good, or recoverable?

Tags: ios, certificate, app-store, metrics, app-store-connect

I have an app in the App Store.  I revoked the distribution certificate (it was about to expire), and I notice that in App Store Connect my metrics have stopped (although my sales still show).

I wasn't planning on releasing a new version for at least a few weeks. If I wait are those missing metrics gone for good, or will the missing data show when I have a version with the new distribution certificate?

I'm trying to decide if I should release a new version with no real changes just to get data collection happening again - the metrics aren't critical for me to see now but I'd like to have them at some point.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Welp, coincidence it is.  A weeks worth of metrics just dropped without a new version being uploaded. Sorry for the false alarm.